# If objective reality does not exist, is the universe different for everyone?

Tags: philosophy-of-physics, quantum-physics

A recent study says that objective reality doesn’t exist and that each persons subjective experience differs. Now I don’t think that the laws of physics work differently for me or anything like that but my qualia is very different than someone who is not neurodivergent (like me) as I have severe mental illness and am possibly on the autism spectrum. Like if you compare someone like Aaron Judge, the professional baseball player topping the world with his home-run tie record, a homeless man with mental retardation and the mind of a brilliant theoretical physicist like Michio Kaku. Each individual perceives the universe in a much different way than each other. So essentially; do their subjective experiences make each have a “different” universe?

Comment: Perhaps I missed this, but please give a reference for the study that says objective reality does not exist?

Comment: "A recent study says that objective reality doesn't exist" oh, well, glad that's settled.

Comment: Even reality exists Kantian philosophy famously advised we cannot claim any sensible and intelligible judgement about them as things-in-themselves, and OTOH one's subjective private qualia experience would always differ from another's even there's objective public reality in the same sense as you cannot find two exactly identical leafs in this contingent world, and common sense suggests each individual simply experiences their own different perspective with their own idiosyncratic background beliefs thrown projected in the publicly sharable phenomenal experiences (or reality if it exists)...

Comment: If the world was limited to our subjective experience people couldn't be killed by bullets they didn't see coming. Between the time the bullet is released and the moment it hits, it must have some kind of reality of its own, somewhere. Sure, we can't compare our qualia and maybe you feel a red apple like I see a yellow one, it does not change the fact the wavelength reflected by the apple will be measured to be the same by both of us. The fact that all we have access to is our own perception of reality do no mean it has no property of its own, independently of us.

Comment: People talk about subjective experience only after they learn how to use "subjective" and "experience" from others. So they coordinate how their universes are by communicating and settle, at least, on a common core. As for the inexplicable residue that cannot be communicated, "same" or "different" do not make much sense there. It is not like they can stay themselves and, at the same time, get out of themselves into others to compare what *it* is like for them and decide whether *it* is different.

Comment: in my opinion, that people introduce subjective elements in reality and its description, is not of such magnitude that allows someone to say there is no objetive reality. In other words the subjective parts are not such, that can make reality purely subjective to each. Of course there are subjective interpretations but these are refinements of what is mostly an objective event.

Comment: Exactly,  if you believe that the laws of pvysics are free creatione of the self, try to violate the law of gravitation flying on the Moon using only the "power of the mind".

Comment: Havingsaid that, irrationalism, ifealism, solipsism are IMO perfectly sound philosophical positions but they have simply nothing to say that is relevant/interesting in order to undestand scientific knowledge. Thus, why their proponents try to do it?

Comment: No. Because each of our realities have our picture of others within them. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indra%27s_net There is no objectivity, only reified intersubjectivity.

Comment: @CriglCragl what is the difference between something objective and something intersubjective? What if subjects agree to defy gravity, can they do it based on their intersubjectivity ?

Comment: I have long wondered why there are not more hard solipsists.

Comment: @NikosM.: The difference is there is no one who experiences objectivity - unless it is God, a la Bishop Berkeley. I'd look to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_Consciousnesses that minds begin at interaction points between being & world (ayatana, sense gates), get integrated into objects of mind, abstracted, then link to the memesphere. Money has reality because of collective decision. But non-linguistic intelligence exists too, engaging directly with experiences. But note 'self' is linguistic, social, not a coherent direct experience

Comment: @CriglCragl money indeed is a socially constructed intersubjective reality but gravity is not

Comment: I have always wondered why there are not more hard solipsists. I keep asking this question and nobody ever answers.

Comment: @BillOnne You should ask this as it's own question. Personally maybe the "wager" is too great, of possibly mistreating other subjective organisms.

Comment: @JKusin Who should I ask if the universe only exists in my own mind?

Comment: You surely don’t know the answer to every question you could ask before asking/experimenting to find out. So you still learn even if it’s self study.

Comment: @ScottRowe. I think [this](https://www.nature.com/articles/s42005-022-00828-z?utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=commission_junction&utm_campaign=CONR_PF018_ECOM_GL_PHSS_ALWYS_DEEPLINK&utm_content=textlink&utm_term=PID100052570&CJEVENT=4ad65bdd5daf11ed80b650610a1c0e0e) might be the study. There are papers working on similar lines which go back a while. [This article](https://www.popularmechanics.com/science/a40460495/objective-reality-may-not-exist/) discusses it in layman's terms.

Comment: @ScottRowe. And [here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Wsjgtp9XZxo), Hossenfelder rejects any conclusion that reality doesn't exist.

Comment: @BillOnne Obviously, because you are the only one. Duh.

Comment: @Futilitarian Thank you. Studying reality and concluding that it doesn't exist would be... inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

Objective reality does exist. How we perceive objective reality is different. Our perceptions are meaningless to the "coding of the matrix" which persists and will always continue to do so. Our human experience has evolved for survival, not to truth. Reason is your only tool for discernment of truth.

Comment: Re. "one’s awareness of other objects distinct from oneself." i.e. objective reality: Kant - Rational Psychology and Self-Knowledge  [4d. Relation to Objects in Space](https://iep.utm.edu/kantmind/#SH4d)

Comment: I consider the issue in my essay The principle of physicalism applied to a few example areas on ResearchGate. I must admit that I am biased in the direction of believing that an objective reality exists. It is the first of my three axioms.